# Bullets combined with numbering for InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to achieve something like a bullet and then a number:

- Recommendation 1-1: Foo

I'd like to have deep control over the bullet.  I've tried a variety of mechanisms including:

- Drop caps
- Nested styles
- Underlining

There is a bullet character available in the (automatic) numbering option but I can't seem to customize the style, though I would prefer to use automatic numbering:

```
^b
```

Is there any way, other than doing the numbers manually, to achieve the look that I want in InDesign?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to insert automatic numbering with the bullet items?

Comment: That's right, and ideally i'd like to style the bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just work with a table. 1 row, 2 columns. The first column is the styled bullet and the second is your numbered List:

[image]

Or, if you don't mind losing the automatic numbering on finish, 
you could make a two-paragraph format. The first would have numbers and the second would have your bullet (and styles). Apply the first format to the list, then right click into the text box and choose "convert numbering to text", then apply bullet format.

Comment: Thanks.  This may be the best approach and indeed it's the one I think i'll need to use, i'll wait for a couple of days and see if there's any other options.

Answer (score 2):

Select "Numbers" as your list type, make sure numbering is selected as your format, and put: `• Recomendation 1-^#:^t` into the field "Number". This will put a Bullet character and some common text before the number.

[image]

Comment: This approach doesn't permit changing of the font.  If I wanted a bullet character in the number format I could use ^B or any character in the current font and at the current size, but as it stands that only gets me part of the way there.

Comment: Just add a Character style with a glyph or icon font for whatever you want the bullet to be styled like.

Comment: The character style doesn't work on the first character.  If I want to have a different font for the bullet, it's impossible based on everything I've seen.